# How to get Arrays from APIs and display them

Tags: javascript

I was playing with Pokemon's API and I was able to get the names and sprites of the pokemons but got stuck when trying to fetch the array.

```
    async function fetchData()
    {
    const pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemonName").value.toLowerCase();

    const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}`);

    const data = await response.json();

    let elementTypes = data.types;
    for(let i = 0; i < elementTypes.length; i++)
        {
            let markup = `<li>${elementTypes[i]}</li>`;

            document.getElementById("pokeTypes").innerHTML = markup;
        }
    }
```

Pokemon can have multiple types and that's 'types' I want to put it in my DIV, which is 'pokeTypes'. I can't seem to throw them into the HTML using a for loop

Comment: The `types` also have properties, you *probably* want `..${elementTypes[i].type.name}...`

Comment: What did you get when you debugged?  ie `console.log(elementTypes[i])`

Comment: Log the `response.json()` to the console and share the output in the OP.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon it's about 20 pages unformatted...

Comment: @freedomn-m A typical 3 elements will do.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You have to use .innerHtml += instead of just =. Also, you better check what actually is in an element of the elementTypes array

Comment: I think, you should convert json response data into object using `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @AlisherNasrullayev you mean like this line `data = await response.json()` - what do you think this does?   Review: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json

Comment: @freedomn-m oh, sorry, I've confused )

Answer (score 1):

```js
    async function fetchData()
    {
    const pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemonName").value.toLowerCase();

    const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}`);

    const data = await response.json();

    let elementTypes = data.types;
    let content = ''
    for(let i = 0; i < elementTypes.length; i++)
        {
            let markup = `<li>${elementTypes[i].type.name}</li>`;

            content = content.concat(markup); // or content += markup
        }
    document.getElementById("pokeTypes").innerHTML = content
    }
```

Need a variable to store each type through the loop. Then set it to the div with id `pokeTypes`. Or it will replace that div content while looping.

Comment: You will need to assign the return value from `content.concat(markup)` back to the `content` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON response of the Pokémon API typically ends in this way:

```
{ ...,
"types":[
  {"slot":1,"type":{"name":"grass","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/"}},
  {"slot":2,"type":{"name":"poison","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/4/"}}],"weight":1000
}
```

So, in order to list all type names of the selected Pokémon you could do something like

```js
const sel=document.querySelector("select");
// get the first 20 Pokémon names and put them as options into the select element:
fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon").then(r=>r.json()).then(p=>{
  sel.innerHTML= p.results.map(r=>`<option>${r.name}</option>`).join("");
  showtypes();
});
sel.addEventListener("change",showtypes);

function showtypes(){ 
 fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${sel.value}`).then(r=>r.json()).then(data=>
  document.querySelector("ul").innerHTML=data.types.map(t=>`<li>${t.type.name}</li>`).join("")
 )
}
```

```html
<select></select>
<ul></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
async function fetchData() {
    const pokemonName = document.getElementById("pokemonName").value.toLowerCase();

    const response = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}`);

    const data = await response.json();

        let elementTypes = data.types;
        let markups = ""; //<== add this line
        // change following codes
        for(let i = 0; i < elementTypes.length; i++)
        {
            markups += `<li>${elementTypes[i]?.type.name}</li>`;
        }
        document.getElementById("pokeTypes").innerHTML = markups;
    }
```